# Python max and min

Tags: python, max, min

I'm pretty new to Python, and what makes me mad about my problem is that I feel like it's really simple.I keep getting an error in line 8. I just want this program to take the numbers the user entered and print the largest and smallest, and I want it to cancel the loop if they enter negative 1.

`'int' object is not iterable` is the error.

```
print "Welcome to The Number Input Program."

number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))

while (number != int(-1)):
    number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))

high = max(number)
low = min(number)

print "The highest number entered was ", high, ".\n"
print "The lowest number entered was ", low, ".\n"

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that `number` is an `int`.  `max` and `min` both require lists (or other iterable things) - so instead, you have to add `number` to a list like so:

```
number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
num_list = []

while (number != int(-1)):
    num_list.append(number)
    number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))

high = max(num_list)
low = min(num_list)
```

Just as a note after reading dr jimbob's answer - my answer assumes that you **don't** want to account for -1 when finding `high` and `low`.

Comment: Completely true, and it should be fixed.  It was that way in the question, however, and I'm a firm believer in providing answer code that deviates as little as possible from question code.

Comment: It was my pleasure. Just so you know (because you're new here), if you choose an answer, it is customary to "accept" it - that is, the little check mark on the left side of the answer. See [the section in the faq](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) or [this post on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more details.

Answer (score 9):

That's cause each time you pass one integer argument to max and min and python doesn't know what to do with it.

Ether pass at least two arguments:

```
least_number = min(number1, number2,...,numbern)
```

or an iterable:

```
least_number = min([number1, number2, ...,numbern])
```

Here's the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max)

Comment: How would I pass multiple numbers to max and min? Thanks for the explanation as to why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change number to an list of numbers.  E.g.,

```
print "Welcome to The Number Input Program."

numbers = []
number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))

while (number != -1):
    numbers.append(number)
    number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))

high = max(numbers)
low = min(numbers)

print "The highest number entered was ", high, ".\n"
print "The lowest number entered was ", low, ".\n"

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525492/1587329), [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) and [`max`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) can also take multiple arguments. To omit the list, you can

```
print "Welcome to The Number Input Program."

number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
high = low = number


while (number != int(-1)):
    number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
    high = max(high, number)
    low = min(low, number)

print "The highest number entered was ", high, ".\n"
print "The lowest number entered was ", low, ".\n"

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = ''
active = True

largest = 0
smallest = 0
while active:
    num = input("Please enter a number")
    if num == 'done': 
        active = False
        break
    else:
        try:
            num = int(num)

            if largest < num:
                largest = num
            if smallest == 0 or smallest > num:
                smallest = num

        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")

print("Largest no. is " + str(largest))
print("Smallest no. is " + str(smallest))
```

Comment: This program will accept any count of numbers entered by user. It also checks for if the input string is a number, otherwise throws error.

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Comment: int object is not iterable. There are 2 ways to overcome the problem. First either define a list as mentioned in the solutions earlier. The second option is compare the number entered by the user with the Max and Min variables defined while iterating in the While loop.